# Get Index names by multiple alias names

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

How to retrieve index name in elastic search based on some given aliases names.
Example:
Index_name: test
Aliases names: a1,a2,a3
Index_name: test2
Aliases name: a1,a3
Index_name: test3
Aliases name: a1
retrieve the index name which has a1,a2,a3 in its alias names.
expected from above example: test

Answer (score 0):

`GET /alias_name`
returns a json with all the indices using the alias.

For this use case, you can try something like below.

`curl -XGET <ES_URL>/_cat/aliases/a1,a2,a3 2>/dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f2 | uniq -c | grep "^[[:space:]]\+3"`

The command prints only indices with all '3' aliases.

Comment: yes you are right. but in my case index has more than one alias name and i want all the indices which contains all the aliases names what i search . In my above example if i want to get all the indices which has a1,a2,a3 (in AND condition) i should get  only “test” index name

Comment: We are not directly using elasticsearch by curl. I am using java high level client so i want a api with some query.

Comment: could so please suggest something

Comment: I can't think of an api that can do this. You might want to raise a ticket in elastic support for advice from the experts.